# Problema navbar bootstrap no Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap

Um cliente pediu para eu aumentar o tamanho da navbar, até aí tudo bem.
Aumentei e não tive problema, porém, quando eu desço a pagina e subo novamente, a navbar vai para trás do slider.

[image: Normal]

[image: Depois]

Comment: Link do site: http://novosite.analubi.com.br/

Comment: Coloque o código na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema com **z-index**.
Deixe assim o seu **navbar** que vai funcionar.

```
.navbar {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #d1d1d1;
    padding-top: 20px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: Caramba, perfeito, era isso mesmo! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se a resposta funcionou, marque ela como "resposta". :D